# can we automate global address list in outlook 2010 using VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, outlook

Can We automate adding/ deleting contacts from Global Address List.
I am trying to develop a tool for my Manager which will add an email to Global Address List when a new person joins our team, remove if a person leaves our team.

I tried searching online but couldn't find  data related to same.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? Can it be a VSTO Outlook extension written in C# or VB.net?

Comment: VB.Net would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The Global Address List differs from Contacts folders in that it is not supposed to be editable by users.  Each entry in the GAL generally represents an Exchange Mailbox/user; changes are made by Exchange administrators.  There is also no way to edit the GAL via the Outlook Object Model.  You need to use other tools to do that - see here:

Updating User Information in the Exchange GAL - Slipstick Systems
http://www.slipstick.com/exchange/updating-user-information-in-the-exchange-gal/

If it is actually Outlook Contacts that you want to work with, then you can easily use the Outlook Object Model to add or delete ContactItem objects in specific folders.

Object model (Outlook 2013 developer reference)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866465.aspx